# Promise result not get assigned to a variable

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, promise

```
import {StorageApiContext,ResumeData} from '../../app/api';
const context = new StorageApiContext();

export function ResumeDataReducer(state={},action){
    var test;
    switch(action.type){
        case "GetResume":{            
            var data= 
            context.ResumeData
            .getAll((odata)=>{return odata.filter("userid eq \'"+action.payload+"\'")
            .select("resumename")}).then((result)=>{ test = result; });
            return {...state,"resumenames":test};
        }        
    }
    return state;
}
```

data variable in the above code is a promise. I need only the result inside the promise. but the variable test is returned with undefined value.
What is the problem in my code?

Comment: reducers are not meant to handle requests, make your api call on your action and use react-thunk to support async operations

Comment: @AngelSalazar I changed the api call to action, and used redux-thunk , it is working fine now. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you made a common mistake. 
You assign value to variable `test` inside the promise asynchronously. However new value to test will be assign *after* completion of your `ResumeDataReducer` function.
So, from my opinion, you need either use async/await or change the logic and return Promise from `ResumeDataReducer`, not value.